# Another frustrating uncaught reference error: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the simplest of functions in grade_picker.js

```
$ ->  
$('#grade_cbl_eval_category_id').change ->
  selected = $(this).attr 'value'
  alert(selected)
  return false
```

Yielding:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
     **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**
  return $('#grade_cbl_eval_category_id').change(function() {
    var selected;
    selected = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(selected);
    return false;
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

In application.js I have

```
$(function() {
$("#grade_picker_dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 810,
    modal: true,
    button: {
        "Done": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
});
```

In the Grades class I do have an attribute named **cbl_eval_category_id**.

I've read quite a few other similar posts, but beeing a newbie I'm following very little.
Looking at these files under rails-root:

```
smiralph@smiralph] find . -exec grep -l "jquery" {} \; 
./.bundle/config
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/rails.js
```

Inside .bundle/config I have:

```
---  
BUNDLE_PATH: jquery-rails  
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
```

Where can I begin looking for what's wrong???

Thanks

---

**EDIT/ADDITION:**
Should have added that almost identical code is working elsewhere.  (Identical to what I originally had before this simple example.)

---

**CLOSURE**
Thanks all, with your help I get it working okay.

Comment: Are you including `jquery` prior to calling these scripts?  Have you Called `jQuery.noConflict()` somewhere?  If you substitute `jQuery` for `$` does it work?

Comment: Try replacing the $ signs with jQuery and see if you get the same reference error.

Comment: Give us your applications.js, or whichever file is serving as your main manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Either your reference to jQuery is after your reference to grade_picker.js, or the jQuery library is not loading on your page.

Comment: You're right! <br/>  The other working jQueries are all alphabetically after the jQuery lib links.  How to I move them < my script w/o renaming them?

Answer (score 2):

try adding the jquery before you add any other dependent js file like

```
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js
./app/assets/javascripts/rails.js
```

Comment: 3nigma,  The `find` statement listed them in the order I pasted it above, but the actual files in the DIR are in that alpha-sorted order.  Thanks.

Comment: order in dir doesnt matter, but the order in which they are reference in the page does matter